# Problems with xamarin for visual studio

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I just installed xamarin from Visual Studio Community setup but i cannot get the basic the basic project to run (Blank App).

I tried with .NET Framework 4.5 and 4.6 .  Also, the emulator for Android 4.4 Api 19 is not starting .

Here are the errors i'm getting : 
[image]

Comment: please follow the articles [xamarin article for starting](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problems by reinstalling xamarin .